# How to ensure that sum of exp function always positive?

Tags: inequality, mathematical-modeling, functional-inequalities

I have a model which looks like

$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^N\lambda_i\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu}_i)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu}_i)\right]
$$

The $\Sigma$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite covariance matrix, and all the squared-exponential functions have same $\Sigma$ matrix.

Now, I want to make sure that $\forall x \in R^d, f(\mathbf{x}) \geq 0$, what constraints should I pose to all the $\lambda_i$?

Posing constraints that all $\lambda_i > 0$ of course works, but that may make my model perform poorly, to make the model accurate, some $\lambda_i$ shoule be less than zero, so, can I further relax the constraints?

Comment: Do you want to allow for negativity or something? Otherwise it is trivial...

Comment: @Ian , I want to allow some \lambda_i to be negative, while maintaining the sum of all the exps to be positive

Comment: All the Gaussians have the same $\Sigma$?

Comment: @Rahul, Yes they do.

Comment: In that case, you could try imposing that all $f(\mu_i)$ are nonnegative. It's not *sufficient* for nonnegativity everywhere, but maybe it's a good enough approximation for your purposes? If the $\Sigma$'s were allowed to be different you could have quite bad cases like $-\exp(-\frac1{20}x^2)+1.1\exp(-\frac12x^2)$.

Comment: @Rahul Actually, in my model $f(\mu_i)$ is always nonnegative, I am using this linear combination of gaussian to fit a nonnegative function, and the $\mu_i$ are my training points.